# Resampling when the DateTime index is not unique and the corresponding value is the same

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `df` DataFrame (`pandas`):

```
           attribute
2017-01-01         a
2017-01-01         a
2017-01-05         b
2017-02-01         a
2017-02-10         a
```

where the first column is a non-unique `datetime` index and I want to count the number of a's and b's on a weekly basis. If I try to `df.attribute.resample('W').count()` there will be an error, because of duplicate entries.

What way can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in a 2-step process involving a `groupby` followed by a `resample`.

```
df.groupby(level=0).count().resample('W').sum()
            attribute
2017-01-01        2.0
2017-01-08        1.0
2017-01-15        NaN
2017-01-22        NaN
2017-01-29        NaN
2017-02-05        1.0
2017-02-12        1.0
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
df=df.reset_index()    
df.groupby([df['index'].dt.week,'attribute']).count()
Out[292]: 
                 index
index attribute       
1     b              1
5     a              1
6     a              1
52    a              2
```

Or

```
df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0).week,'attribute'])['attribute'].count()

Out[303]: 
    attribute
1   b            1
5   a            1
6   a            1
52  a            2
Name: attribute, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Interesting, but are you sure this gives the right answer?

Comment: I think OP wanted to resample on every week, rather than just extract the week and count associated with it. Still, you have my upvote. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though I a more interested in resample on a weekly basis.

Comment: @thanasissdr great  , At least I know what you need ~ :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) to group the index by a weekly frequency:

```
In [83]: df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).count()
Out[83]: 
            attribute
2017-01-01          2
2017-01-08          1
2017-01-15          0
2017-01-22          0
2017-01-29          0
2017-02-05          1
2017-02-12          1
```

To group by both a weekly frequency and the `attribute` column you could use:

```
In [87]: df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W'), 'attribute']).size()
Out[87]: 
            attribute
2017-01-01  a            2
2017-01-08  b            1
2017-02-05  a            1
2017-02-12  a            1
dtype: int64
```

`pd.Grouper` also has a `key` parameter which allows you to group by datetimes located in a column rather than the index.

Comment: Great! This seems useful, too!