# Python re-sampling time series data which can not be indexed

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

The purpose of this question is to know how many trades "happened" in each second (count) as well as the total volume traded (sum).

I have time series data which can not be indexed (as there are multiply entries with the same time-stamp - can get many trades on the same millisecond) and therefor the use of [resample](http://benalexkeen.com/resampling-time-series-data-with-pandas/) as explained here can not work.

Another approach was to first to do group by time as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46635765/resampling-when-the-datetime-index-is-not-unique-and-the-corresponding-value-is) (and later to resample per seconds). The problem is that grouping will cause only one elementary arithmetic over the grouped items (I can only sum/mean/std etc.) while in this data, I would need for 'tradeVolume' column to be grouped by sum while column 'ask1' to be grouped by mean.

So my question is/are:
1. how to `group by` with different arithmetic per column
and if not possible is there any other way to resample the milliseconds data into seconds without the datetime index.

Thanks!

The time series (sample) is here:

```
SecurityID,dateTime,ask1,ask1Volume,bid1,bid1Volume,ask2,ask2Volume,bid2,bid2Volume,ask3,ask3Volume,bid3,bid3Volume,tradePrice,tradeVolume,isTrade
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052240,12869.0,1,12868.0,3,12870.0,19,12867.5,2,12872.5,2,12867.0,1,0.0,0,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052260,12869.0,1,12868.0,3,12870.0,19,12867.5,2,12872.5,2,12867.0,1,12861.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052260,12869.0,1,12868.0,2,12870.0,19,12867.5,2,12872.5,2,12867.0,1,12868.0,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052270,12869.0,1,12868.0,2,12870.0,19,12867.5,2,12872.5,2,12867.0,1,12868.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052270,12869.0,1,12868.0,1,12870.0,19,12867.5,2,12872.5,2,12867.0,1,12868.0,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052282,12869.0,1,12868.0,1,12870.0,19,12867.5,2,12872.5,2,12867.0,1,12868.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052282,12869.0,1,12867.5,2,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12868.0,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052291,12869.0,1,12867.5,2,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12867.5,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052291,12869.0,1,12867.5,1,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12867.5,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315,12869.0,1,12867.5,1,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12867.5,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315,12869.0,1,12867.5,1,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12867.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315,12869.0,1,12867.5,1,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12865.5,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315,12869.0,1,12867.5,1,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12865.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315,12869.0,1,12867.5,1,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12864.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315,12869.0,1,12861.5,2,12870.0,19,12861.0,1,12872.5,2,12860.0,5,12864.0,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052335,12869.0,1,12861.5,2,12870.0,19,12861.0,1,12872.5,2,12860.0,5,12861.5,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052335,12869.0,1,12861.5,1,12870.0,19,12861.0,1,12872.5,2,12860.0,5,12861.5,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052348,12869.0,1,12861.5,1,12870.0,19,12861.0,1,12872.5,2,12860.0,5,12861.5,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052348,12869.0,1,12861.0,1,12870.0,19,12860.0,5,12872.5,2,12859.5,3,12861.5,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052357,12869.0,1,12861.0,1,12870.0,19,12860.0,5,12872.5,2,12859.5,3,12861.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052357,12869.0,1,12860.0,5,12870.0,19,12859.5,3,12872.5,2,12858.0,1,12861.0,1,0
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to compute the mean for ask1 and the sum for tradeVolume per group, where each group contain all trades within one second?

Comment: yes. per same group (for example group:2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315). only this way i could later index the df by dateTime and than resample it (or am I wrong here to?)

Comment: "how to group by with different arithmetic per column" - What about `df.groupby.agg()` and pass a dict of functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>First you need to have a column for the seconds (since epoch), then `groupby` using that column, and then do an aggregation on the columns you want.</strike>

You want to floor the timestamp down to one second accuracy, and group using that. Then apply an aggregation to get the mean/sum/std what ever you need

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['dateTime'] = df['dateTime'].astype('datetime64[s]')
groups = df.groupby('dateTime')
groups.agg({'ask1': np.mean, 'tradeVolume': np.sum})
```

I modified the data to make sure there are actually different seconds in it,

```
SecurityID,dateTime,ask1,ask1Volume,bid1,bid1Volume,ask2,ask2Volume,bid2,bid2Volume,ask3,ask3Volume,bid3,bid3Volume,tradePrice,tradeVolume,isTrade
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052240,12869.0,1,12868.0,3,12870.0,19,12867.5,2,12872.5,2,12867.0,1,0.0,0,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052260,12869.0,1,12868.0,3,12870.0,19,12867.5,2,12872.5,2,12867.0,1,12861.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052260,12869.0,1,12868.0,2,12870.0,19,12867.5,2,12872.5,2,12867.0,1,12868.0,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052270,12869.0,1,12868.0,2,12870.0,19,12867.5,2,12872.5,2,12867.0,1,12868.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052270,12869.0,1,12868.0,1,12870.0,19,12867.5,2,12872.5,2,12867.0,1,12868.0,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052282,12869.0,1,12868.0,1,12870.0,19,12867.5,2,12872.5,2,12867.0,1,12868.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052282,12869.0,1,12867.5,2,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12868.0,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052291,12869.0,1,12867.5,2,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12867.5,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052291,12869.0,1,12867.5,1,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12867.5,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315,12869.0,1,12867.5,1,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12867.5,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:09.052315,12869.0,1,12867.5,1,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12867.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:10.052315,12869.0,1,12867.5,1,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12865.5,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:10.052315,12869.0,1,12867.5,1,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12865.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:10.052315,12869.0,1,12867.5,1,12870.0,19,12867.0,1,12872.5,2,12865.5,1,12864.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:10.052315,12869.0,1,12861.5,2,12870.0,19,12861.0,1,12872.5,2,12860.0,5,12864.0,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:10.052335,12869.0,1,12861.5,2,12870.0,19,12861.0,1,12872.5,2,12860.0,5,12861.5,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:10.052335,12869.0,1,12861.5,1,12870.0,19,12861.0,1,12872.5,2,12860.0,5,12861.5,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:10.052348,12869.0,1,12861.5,1,12870.0,19,12861.0,1,12872.5,2,12860.0,5,12861.5,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:10.052348,12869.0,1,12861.0,1,12870.0,19,12860.0,5,12872.5,2,12859.5,3,12861.5,1,0
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:10.052357,12869.0,1,12861.0,1,12870.0,19,12860.0,5,12872.5,2,12859.5,3,12861.0,1,1
2318276,2017-11-20 08:00:10.052357,12869.0,1,12860.0,5,12870.0,19,12859.5,3,12872.5,2,12858.0,1,12861.0,1,0
```

and the output

```
In [53]: groups.agg({'ask1': np.mean, 'tradeVolume': np.sum})
Out[53]: 
               ask1  tradeVolume
seconds                         
1511164809  12869.0           10
1511164810  12869.0           10
```

---

footnote

OP said that the original version (below) was faster, so I ran some timings

```
def test1(df):
    """This is the fastest and cleanest."""
    df['dateTime'] = df['dateTime'].astype('datetime64[s]')
    groups = df.groupby('dateTime')
    agg = groups.agg({'ask1': np.mean, 'tradeVolume': np.sum})

def test2(df):
    """Totally unnecessary amount of datetime floors."""
    def group_by_second(index_loc):
        return df.loc[index_loc, 'dateTime'].floor('S')
    df['dateTime'] = df['dateTime'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
    groups = df.groupby(group_by_second)
    result = groups.agg({'ask1': np.mean, 'tradeVolume': np.sum})

def test3(df):
    """Original version, but the conversion to/from nanoseconds is unnecessary."""
    df['dateTime'] = df['dateTime'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
    df['seconds'] = df['dateTime'].apply(lambda v: v.value // 1e9)
    groups = df.groupby('dateTime')
    agg = groups.agg({'ask1': np.mean, 'tradeVolume': np.sum})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print('22 rows')
    df = pd.read_csv('data_small.csv')
    print('test1', timeit.repeat("test1(df.copy())", number=50, globals=globals()))
    print('test2', timeit.repeat("test2(df.copy())", number=50, globals=globals()))
    print('test3', timeit.repeat("test3(df.copy())", number=50, globals=globals()))

    print('220 rows')
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    print('test1', timeit.repeat("test1(df.copy())", number=50, globals=globals()))
    print('test2', timeit.repeat("test2(df.copy())", number=50, globals=globals()))
    print('test3', timeit.repeat("test3(df.copy())", number=50, globals=globals()))
```

I tested those on two datasets one 10 times the size of the first one, the results

```
22 rows
test1 [0.08138518501073122, 0.07786444900557399, 0.0775048139039427]
test2 [0.2644687460269779, 0.26298125297762454, 0.2618108610622585]
test3 [0.10624988097697496, 0.1028324980288744, 0.10304366517812014]
220 rows
test1 [0.07999306707642972, 0.07842653687112033, 0.07848454895429313]
test2 [1.9794962559826672, 1.966513831866905, 1.9625889619346708]
test3 [0.12691736104898155, 0.12642419710755348, 0.126510804053396]
```

So, best to use the `.astype('datetime[s]')` version as that is the fastest and scales the best.

Comment: thanks!. 1. have to do an int division here = ? 2.1000000000 = is this the # of rows in file?

Comment: `int` division means that the division returns an integer, i.e. disregards decimals and rounds the result up to the closest second. The `.astype(np.datetime64)` conversion converts the `dateTime` column into pandas `Timestamp` which represent time in nanosecond accuracy, to get from nano seconds to seconds you divide by `1000000000`. I just found a much more readable way of doing that, see edits above

Comment: 1. first method took 0.111 seconds to complete while 2nd (edited) method took almost 3 full minutes!!!. also on the first method the "look" of the seconds is serialized and i need to figure out how to translate it again to some readable format. while on the edited, the format is same.

Comment: is that a question?

Comment: yes. sorry for the bad writing. if I choose the first method "df['seconds'] = df['dateTime'].apply(lambda v: v.value // 1000000000)" which is faster, how do I change the seconds to be viewed is regulate time format?

Comment: @Giladbi I learned something about `pandas` datetimes today. It turns out the `.astype(datetime64)` conversion can be done directly to a specified accuracy, this is also the fastest, see updated answer above. If you need to keep the `dateTime` column as under one second accuracy, just assign the converted `dateTime` to a new column, for instance `seconds` and use that in the `groupby`.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. I tried this and although my dateTime is type        datetime64[ns] I am getting an error: TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [datetime64[s]]. I found that this can work only if the dateTime is an object. thanks again!

Comment: yeah I noticed that as well, you can't convert an already converted `datetime[ns]`, which makes sense