# Manipulating time series data in python: summing series and aggregating over a time period

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to figure how to visualize some sensor data. I have data collected every 5 minutes for multiple devices, stored in a JSON structure that looks something like this (note that I don't have control over the data structure):

```
[
  {
    "group": { "id": "01234" },
    "measures": {
      "measures": {
        "...device 1 uuid...": {
          "metric.name.here": {
            "mean": [
              ["2019-04-17T14:30:00+00:00", 300, 1],
              ["2019-04-17T14:35:00+00:00", 300, 2],
              ...
            ]
          }
        },
        "...device 2 uuid...": {
          "metric.name.here": {
            "mean": [
              ["2019-04-17T14:30:00+00:00", 300, 0],
              ["2019-04-17T14:35:00+00:00", 300, 1],
              ...
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Each tuple of the form `["2019-04-17T14:30:00+00:00", 300, 0]` is `[timestamp, granularity, value]`. Devices are grouped by project id. Within any given group, I want to take the data for multiple devices and sum them together.  E.g., for the above sample data, I want the final series to look like:

```
["2019-04-17T14:30:00+00:00", 300, 1],
["2019-04-17T14:35:00+00:00", 300, 3],
```

The series are not necessarily the same length.

Lastly, I want to aggregate these measurements into hourly samples.

I can get the individual series like this:

```
with open('data.json') as fd:
  data = pd.read_json(fd)

for i, group in enumerate(data.group):
    project = group['project_id']
    instances = data.measures[i]['measures']
    series_for_group = []
    for instance in instances.keys():
        measures = instances[instance][metric][aggregate]

        # build an index from the timestamps
        index = pd.DatetimeIndex(measure[0] for measure in measures)

        # extract values from the data and link it to the index
        series = pd.Series((measure[2] for measure in measures),
                           index=index)

        series_for_group.append(series)
```

At the bottom of the outer `for` loop, I have an array of `pandas.core.series.Series` objects representing the different sets of measurements associated with the current group.  I was hoping I could simply add them together as in `total = sum(series_for_group)` but that produces invalid data.

1. Am I even reading in this data correctly? This is the first time I've worked with Pandas; I'm not sure if (a) create an index followed by (b) populate the data is the correct procedure here.
2. How would I successfully sum these series together?
3. How would I resample this data into 1-hour intervals? Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379224/python-re-sampling-time-series-data-which-can-not-be-indexed) it looks as if the `.groupby` and `.agg` methods are of interest, but it's not clear from that example how to specify the interval size.

**Update 1**

Maybe I can use `concat` and `groupby`?  E.g.:

```
final = pd.concat(all_series).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Comment: I am not sure looping is a way to go. You may want to fully inflate your data and aggregate them to one big data frame and work on that.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to "inflate my data".

Comment: I mean something very similar to your code, but pull all the information together and append to a big dataframe. This data frame has single datatype for each column, which is not `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with what seems like a working solution based on the code in my question. On my system, this takes about 6 seconds to process about 85MB of input data.  In comparison, I cancelled Quang's code after 5 minutes.

I don't know if this is the Right Way to process this data, but it produces apparently correct results. I notice that building a list of series, as in this solution, and then making a single `pd.concat` call is more performant than putting `pd.concat` inside the loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import click
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


@click.command()
@click.option('-a', '--aggregate', default='mean')
@click.option('-p', '--projects')
@click.option('-r', '--resample')
@click.option('-o', '--output')
@click.argument('metric')
@click.argument('datafile', type=click.File(mode='rb'))
def plot_metric(aggregate, projects, output, resample, metric, datafile):

    # Read in a list of project id -> project name mappings, then
    # convert it to a dictionary.
    if projects:
        _projects = pd.read_json(projects)
        projects = {_projects.ID[n]: _projects.Name[n].lstrip('_')
                    for n in range(len(_projects))}
    else:
        projects = {}

    data = pd.read_json(datafile)
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    for i, group in enumerate(data.group):
        project = group['project_id']
        project = projects.get(project, project)

        devices = data.measures[i]['measures']
        all_series = []
        for device, measures in devices.items():
            samples = measures[metric][aggregate]
            index = pd.DatetimeIndex(sample[0] for sample in samples)
            series = pd.Series((sample[2] for sample in samples),
                               index=index)
            all_series.append(series)

        # concatenate all the measurements for this project, then
        # group them using the timestamp and sum the values.
        final = pd.concat(all_series).groupby(level=0).sum()

        # resample the data if requested
        if resample:
            final = final.resample(resample).sum()

        # add series to dataframe
        df[project] = final

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    df.plot(ax=ax, figsize=(11, 8.5))
    ax.legend(frameon=False, loc='upper right', ncol=3)

    if output:
        plt.savefig(output)
        plt.close()
    else:
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot_metric()
```

Answer (score 1):

What I suggested in the comment is to do something like this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({}, columns=['timestamp', 'granularity', 'value',
                               'project', 'uuid', 'metric', 'agg'])
for i, group in enumerate(data.group):
    project = group['id']
    instances = data.measures[i]['measures']

    series_for_group = []


    for device, measures in instances.items():
        for metric, aggs in measures.items():
            for agg, lst in aggs.items():
                sub_df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ['timestamp', 'granularity', 'value'])
                sub_df['project'] = project
                sub_df['uuid'] = device
                sub_df['metric'] = metric
                sub_df['agg'] = agg

                result = pd.concat((result,sub_df), sort=True)

# parse date:
result['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(result['timestamp'])
```

Which results in a data that looks like this

```
    agg     granularity         metric  project     timestamp           uuid                value
0   mean    300     metric.name.here    01234   2019-04-17 14:30:00     ...device 1 uuid...     1
1   mean    300     metric.name.here    01234   2019-04-17 14:35:00     ...device 1 uuid...     2
0   mean    300     metric.name.here    01234   2019-04-17 14:30:00     ...device 2 uuid...     0
1   mean    300     metric.name.here    01234   2019-04-17 14:35:00     ...device 2 uuid...     1
```

then you can do overall aggregation

```
result.resample('H', on='timestamp').sum()
```

which gives:

```
timestamp
2019-04-17 14:00:00    4
Freq: H, Name: value, dtype: int64
```

or groupby aggregation:

```
result.groupby('uuid').resample('H', on='timestamp').value.sum()
```

which gives:

```
uuid                 timestamp          
...device 1 uuid...  2019-04-17 14:00:00    3
...device 2 uuid...  2019-04-17 14:00:00    1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: You said, "I am not sure looping is a way to go", but this solution makes use of deeply nested loops. I tried running this and after five minutes it was still going; something is awry here because my code completes in about 6 seconds.  I'll post it later this evening and maybe we can figure out the difference.

Comment: @larsks yes, I put the code there just to show how the final data frame looks like. I didn't expect extreme performance of the nested for loops anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To construct a dataframe (df) from series with different lengths(for example s1, s2, s3) you can try:

```
df=pd.concat([s1,s2,s3], ignore_index=True, axis=1).fillna('')
```

Once you have your dataframe constructed:

1. Ensure all dates are stored as timestamp objects:

   df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

Then, Add another column to extract the hours from the date column:

```
df['Hour']=df['Date'].dt.hour
```

And then group  by hours and sum up the values:

```
df.groupby('Hour').sum()
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of this vs. using `.resample('H').sum()`?